# Raphael elements event handlers not working for outline mode

Tags: raphael

Raphael elements event handlers are executed only when the element is filled.

Click event handlers are not executed when the element has no fill. Mouseover events behave differently, (both mouseover and mouseout are triggered.) for non filled elements.

My code:http://jsfiddle.net/U5wda/1/

Why is this so ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might want to check out this [article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/pointer-events) on pointer-events. As you can see in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cordesmj/E8YuM/), if you set pointer-events to 'fill', I think this works the way you want. Keep in mind, though, that this will probably not work in IE, since Raphael does not use SVG in IE.

Basically, `pointer-events: fill` causes the element to act like it is filled for mouse events.

Comment: Fixed for me - click events will literally pass through the "hollow" object with no fill and land on the objects below, so no mouse events get triggered. Nifty fix Mike. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You may already realize that when the element is not fill, 
Raphael draws only the border of the figur, right?

If you click correctly at the border of the element ( which is very unlikely cause the border-width is too small) the event will trigger anyway.

So nothing's wrong with the event handle, but you should fill your element with color or fill: transparent.

Comment: fill of transparent is not working. Yes clicking the outline is working. But the mouse over events are not working.

Comment: don't use transparent, i mistook it. But i can confirm not filled element works with all click and mouseover, mouseout, hover event.

Comment: mouseover, mouseout are behaving very differently. pls check the fiddle

Comment: I checked and it worked perfect with both mouseout and mouseover